# lambda closure type and default argument in function template

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

The following code seems ok according to **[expr.prim.lambda]**:

```
#include<functional>

typedef int(*func1)(int);
typedef std::function<int(int)> func2;

int function(int)
{
    return 0;
}

template<typename F = func1>
int function1(F f = function)
{
    return 0;
}

template<typename F = func2>
int function2(F f = function)
{
    return 0;
}

template<typename F = func1>
int function3(F f = [](int i){return 0;})
{
    return 0;
}

template<typename F = func2>
int function4(F f = [](int i){return 0;})
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, gcc (4.8.1) complains about `function3` and `function4` and shows the error

> default argument for template parameter for class enclosing
>   '__lambda'

Can someone explain this error?

Comment: at least you can't do `f = function`, there is std::function template defined. :)

Comment: This code looks legal to me, [clang trunk seems to agree](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7cf1a0be5b9968fe2286ac3ff050a78f-0746f3e88234b09a84c3eb092b83e0d1). I'm tempted to say it's a GCC bug.

Comment: @Casey yes clang 3.3 and microsoft v120 are accepting the code. a gcc bug is not impossible

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest a workaround?

Remove the default template argument for `function3` (and `function4`):

```
template<typename F>
int function3(F f = [](int i){return 0;})
{
    return 0;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
function3<func1>();
```

but I guess you want to be able to call like this:

```
function3();
```

Don't you? Then, create another overload of `function3` which is a function and not a template function:

```
int function3(func1 f = [](int i){return 0;})
{
    return function3<func1>(f);
}
```

Comment: `int function3() { return function3([](int i) {return 0; }) }` seemed more pleasing.